# function to serialize arraylist and another one to deserialize

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I want to establish a function that serialize an `ArrayList` of objects and another one the deserialize the `ArryList`. That is,

```
public void serializeArrays(ArrayList<?> array,String className){
    FileOutputStream fileOut= null;
    ObjectOutputStream out=null;
    try {
      fileOut = new FileOutputStream("../Files/"+className+".ser");
       out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
      out.writeObject(array);
      fileOut.close();
      out.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That code will serialize an object of `ArrayList`, does it mean that **all the objects** of the `Arraylis`t will be serialized, or only the first object so I have to loop on the whole array?

And the problem with deserializing is that the return type can not be `ArrayList` as the objects are not of a fixed class so I made it return an `Object` so I would cast the return value. Is that good way to handle it?

```
public Object deserializeArrays(String className){
    try {
      FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("../Files/"+className+".ser");
      ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
      return in.readObject();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ie) {
      ie.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ce) {
      System.out.println(" "+className+" class not found");
      ce.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem in that code is that I could not close the `fileIn` & `in`, 
and if I put it at finally, an error is reported says:

> unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

And also another error is reported

> error: missing return statement

Answer (score 0):

> that code will serialize an object of ArrayList, does it mean that all the objects of the Arraylist will be serialized ? or only the first object so I have to loop on the whole array

If that code actually works, serializing a collection will serialize all the items it holds (provided they are all `Serializeable`, otherwise you get an exception).

> And the problem with deserializing that the return type can not be ArrayList as the objects are not of a fixed class so I made the return of Object class so I would cast the return value is that good way to handle it ?,

Doesn't matter what the type of the objects in the list is. You deserialize it into an `ArrayList` by casting.

> And also another error is reported
>
> > error: missing return statement

Because you don't have a `return` statement. You're supposed to return the `ArrayList`.

Comment: for point 2,3 : I could not cast in the method as I do not know which class that I should cast to, so I wanted to return just an Object and cast it in the main.
Also I put the 'return' in the try statement and if I put it after try- catch, this error is reported:  _error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    return in.readObject();_

Comment: @Ammar you do know what class you cast to - ArrayList. Also, you're already catching `IOException`, and the method you posted doesn't give me that error.

Comment: Firstly, yeah I could cast the return to ArrayList but then how could I know the class type? I mean ArrayList<SomeClass> could I just cast it into ArrayList and then cast the result again into ArrayList<SomeClass> I just wanted to return the result of reading by readObject() method and cast the result at usage of the method.
the error in the above is _error: missing return statement  }_ and If I added the  'return' after try- catch, this error is reported: _error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught,_  So where should I return the value?

Comment: @Ammar You use the same generic type you declare in your method argument. You're using <?> so that's what you have.